# python.h:no such file or directory error in Qtcreator

Tags: python, c++, qt-creator

I am using Qtcreator to design some forms and I wanted to call a python script on button click in my form. But when I use:

```
#include <Python.h>
```

I get the following error:

```
python.h: no such file or directory
```

I went through many links which give a reason why this error is caused and I was not able to understand. I just started using the Qt creator and I am not able to figure out how to handle it. All the links related to this error mention about including the path to the python library,making changes to the .pro file but I have no idea how I can do it through Qt creator and what is to be done exactly. When I run the command "locate Python.h"  in the terminal I get the following output:

```
/usr/include/python2.7/Python.h
```

So I have the python-dev installed on my debian. Could you let me know in details on how I can resolve this issue. I am looking for a way to include the libraries so that I can used other libraries like QtGUI, tango etc in the similar way.

Comment: i think you need to add `/usr/include/python2.7/` to your library include path

Comment: @JoranBeasley I understand that it should be included in my library path but I am not sure where I can find my library path and what exactly needs to be modified.

Answer (score 3):

To correctly include pyhton's header in a QT project do the following:

1. Add the `#include` in your header file

   ```
   #include <Python.h>
   ```
2. In the `.pro` file of your project insert

   ```
   CONFIG += no_keywords # Python redefines some qt keywords
   INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include/python<version>
   LIBS += -lpython<version>
   ```
3. According to [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html#using-qt-with-3rd-party-signals-and-slots) replace `slots` with `Q_SLOTS` and so on...

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to change your project.pro to add pkg-config, and look for (in your case) python-2.7. Running:

```
pkg-config --cflags python-2.7
```

you'll see the directory is included

Comment: I have my Project.pro which includes a entry called HEADERS should that be modified? Or should I be adding a new entry that you mentioned above?

Comment: Nop, you need something like this [link](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qmake-project-files.html#configuration-features)